# Xubuntu 13.10: wifi hard blocked on Lenovo T520

Tags: wireless, xubuntu, lenovo

I have Xubuntu 13.10 running on a Lenovo T520 laptop. Everything worked just fine, but today, when I was in the middle of a Skype call, my laptop just disconnected from Wi-Fi. And now it says `Wi-Fi is disabled by hardware switch` in the networking menu.

I tried `rfkill unblock all`, but with no effect: `rfkill list all` still says:

```
phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: yes
```

The Wi-Fi switch hotkey (Fn+F5) doesn't have any effect as well. Also I tried pressing Fn+F5 while booting the system but with no effect. I noticed that the Wi-Fi indicator LED below the screen is now always off, even on system reboot.

Can this mean that my Wi-Fi controller is damaged?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe, the wireless switch got turned off. You can see the location of the switch [here](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/product-and-parts/detail.page?&DocID=PD025345). It's component #7.

Answer (score 0):

Try those commands:

1. `sudo rfkill unblock all`
2. `rmmod ath5k && modprobe ath5k`
3. `rm /dev/rfkill`
4. `sudo iwconfig wlan0 txpower auto`